# Meteor, TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined. Getting the _id from from a post parameter

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

I've just started to have a play with meteor and I'm slowly moving a 
NodeJS/Express app over to meteor. However on my blog section, I can't seem to get a single post _id into the helper. With NodeJS alone, I could use req.params._id.

Using the Differential boilerplate as a starting poing, (still using insecure and autopublish in dev) I have this:

```
//both/controllers/post.js

PostController = AppController.extend({

  waitOn: function() {
    return this.subscribe('posts');
  },

     data: function () {
      return Posts.findOne({_id:this.params._id});
    }

});
```

And in the router file

```
//both/router/router.js

Router.route('/posts/:_id', {
    name: 'post'
});
```

The links on the main blog listing page, to the single posts are formated as follows.

```
//client/templates/blog/blog.html

<h3><a href="{{pathFor 'post'}}" class="title">{{ title }}</a></h3>
```

Then the helper file which seems to be the issue?

```
// /client/templates/post/post.js

Template.post.rendered = function() {
};

Template.post.helpers({
     data: function () {
      return Posts.findOne({_id:this.params._id});
    }

});

Template.post.helpers({
    createdAtFormatted: function () {
            return moment(this.createdAt).fromNow();

    }  

});
```

I've tried this.params._id, request.params.id, req.params._id,
And other than  setting an on click event and setting the _id in session (I don't like this idea, if it will even work efficiently/effectively). I'm stuck on ideas.

Comment: Why do you have a `data` helper if your controller is setting the context for you? It seems like you don't need it to begin with because the context of your template is a post document.

Comment: That is also what I'm trying to get my head around. Using it from an example within the boilerplate. for showing a list post 'Items'.

Comment: So the answer seems to be: just remove the `data` helper. `this` is already a post.

Comment: thanks, I've removed that. but it still won't show the requested data. it loads the template fine. just no data from db.